# How to make const only lvalue in a constructor with std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor, perfect-forwarding

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 >
MyClass(T1 && v1, T2 && v2)
    : m_v1(std::forward< T1 >(v1))
    , m_v2(std::forward< T2 >(v2))
{}
```

Let us have a class, named `MyClass`, its constructor showed above. In case without `std::forward` we have to write 4 different constructors:

```
MyClass(SomeType&& v1, SomeType&& v2);
MyClass(SomeType&& v1, const SomeType& v2);
MyClass(const SomeType& v1, SomeType&& v2);
MyClass(const SomeType& v1, const SomeType& v2);
```

Here we use `const SomeType&`, because we don’t want to change our lvalue. Of course, we have `const_cast`, but it’s easy to find such `cast`. The same time, our template constructor with `std::forward` generates constructors with argument type something like this: `SomeType&` - without `const` and therefore we can change the lvalue in the body of our constructor.

**Question:** What is the correct solution? Should I add `const` (how to do it?) or just write the body of my constructors in a proper way - so, they won’t change the lvalue. In case with adding `const` we will get something like this: `const T1&&` and if we give rvalue to constructor, we can’t move it, because it will be constant rvalue. I suppose, that we have to add `const` only if we give lvalue.

I’m trying to prevent `n = 555;` here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <ciso646>

class A
{
public:
    using number_t = std::int32_t;
    using string_t = std::string;

    template < typename T >
    using vector_t = std::vector < T >;

public:
    template < typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, 
        typename Dummy = std::enable_if_t < std::is_same < number_t, 
        typename std::decay < T1 > ::type > ::value > >
    A(T1 && n, T2 && s, T3 && v) :
        m_n { std::forward < T1 > (n) },
        m_s { std::forward < T2 > (s) },
        m_v { std::forward < T3 > (v) } 
    {
        n = 555;
    }

public:
    number_t              m_n;
    string_t              m_s;
    vector_t < number_t > m_v;
};

int main()
{
    A::number_t                 n { 666 };
    A::string_t                 s { "hello" };
    A::vector_t < A::number_t > v { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << n << std::endl;

    A a1(n, s, v);
    A a2(1, "hello", std::vector<A::number_t>( { 4, 5, 6 } ));

    std::cout << n << std::endl;

    A a3(1, "hello", std::vector<int>( { 4, 5, 6 } ));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? We can't know what the correct solution is without knowing what the goal is.

Comment: Disable non-const lvalue ref with 'enable_if'

Comment: @NicolBolas added my code into Q

Comment: If `A` has a non-const lvalue constructor that fiddles with the parameter, that is a problem with `A` not something `MyClass` should worry about. Even if you pass a const reference, an evil `A` could use a const_cast and still modify the parameter.

Comment: @BoPersson I know about const_cast - I think it is bad ability (as many other casts) but if I write const SomeType& value - it is more safety than without const

Comment: @BoPersson and I don’t understand what do u mean that MyClass should worry about smth. MyClass is just an example, main code is with A class

Comment: I thought `A` was supposed to be an example of what `T1` could be in `MyClass`.

Comment: @BoPersson no, MyClass and A are just different names of one class, sorry, but I added code with A-class later and didn’t change MyClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m trying to prevent `n = 555;` here:

You took parameters by forwarding reference. Which means that your intent is that the behavior they deduce to is ultimately determined by what the *caller* provides.

If the caller provides a non-`const` lvalue, then you *get* a non-`const` lvalue. If the caller provides a `const` lvalue, then that's what you get.

Since you intend to forward these parameters into their eventual objects, your intent is to be able to modify them if you are passed an rvalue. And therefore you cannot make them `const`.

Just leave things as they are. The way to prevent `n = 555;` is to *not write it*.

Comment: Ok, I will do so (not to wtite it). But before rvalue refs and move semantics I used const SomeType& value mainly and very rare SomeType& value and it was a good practice.